# Prawn PDFs not formatting correctly when using pdf = pdfname.new in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I have a list of attendances at different teaching events stored in the attendance model, and I want to create certificates based upon this data.

My problem is that none of the prawn formatting seems to work. I cannot change text size, weight, position, use a template etc. Nothing seems to work correctly.

My code is as follows:

show method in attendances_controller

```
 def show
    @attendance = Attendance.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @attendance }

      format.pdf do
         pdf = CertificatePdf.new(@attendance)
         send_data pdf.render, type: "application/pdf", disposition: "inline", filename: "Certificate"
      end
    end
  end
```

certificate_pdf.rb

```
class CertificatePdf < Prawn::Document
  def initialize(attendance)

    start_new_page(:template => "/pdfs/certificate_template.pdf")
    @attendance = attendance

    attendance_info
  end

  def attendance_info
    move_down(70)
    text "This is to certify that"
    text "#{@attendance.student.fname}" + " " + "#{@attendance.student.lname}", :size => 24
    text "Attended the " "#{@attendance.teaching_session.title}" + " " + "#{@attendance.teaching_session.teaching_format.format}"
    text "On " "#{@attendance.teaching_session.date}"
  end
end
```

If anyone could please advise I would be immensely grateful.

Best Wishes,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding the `initialize` method, so the `initialize` method from `Prawn::Document` (where all of the document setup happens) is not being executed.

You should call `super` in your overridden `initialize` method. Note that you'll probably need an empty set of params (using `super()`), otherwise your `attendance` object will be passed to `Prawn::Document.new` and it won't know what to do with it:

```
def initialize(attendance)
  super()

  start_new_page(:template => "/pdfs/certificate_template.pdf")
  @attendance = attendance

  attendance_info
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dylan-markow. Ive added the super() call to my overwritten initialize method, but still no joy! The text and attributes from the attendance model display perfectly, but with no formatting or template. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What version of prawn are you using?

I think in the latest release they moved to a formatted_text method that you'd call like so:

```
formatted_text [ {:text => "Text you want to format.", :size => 24 } ]
```

See the prawn manual section on text/formatted_text.rb:

http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/manual.pdf